# gui development toolkit for linux and windows

Tags: user-interface

I would like to have some advice from my linux programmer friends, on a gui toolkit that I should learn.

I would like to learn a gui toolkit where I can write a program for a gui application that can work both in linux and windows. I mean platform independent gui toolkit. It should be simple and easy to learn.

So that with little effort I can do gui programming for both the OS.

Another point is, that library should be less memory hungry. I mean lite one.

Comment: no bar. that should be easier to learn.

Comment: Sorry, but is `no bar` a programming language? Or what do you mean? Note that you'll need to pick at least one language for software _development_.

Comment: sorry, I mean, any language is fine for me. I know C, C++, but if a good gui toolkit is available with other language, and if its language is easier to learn then I have no problem in going ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-platform programming you might want to look into JVM based languages (most notably Java, but Scala, Groovy etc. might be fine) which provide the Swing gui framework.

Additionally there are other platform independent languages like Python etc.

As for C++ there GUI toolkits like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) or [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org).